# Disabling a button till user decides to enable it in swift

Tags: swift, button

I am trying to build a contact app and want to add a button to favourite a contact.

I want to disable the button till the user unfavourites the contact in some later stage (or never)

I have gone through plenty stacks but all of them give information for disabling a button just once. Once the view changes the button is again enabled.

Please somebody help.

Comment: This will do:- yourButton.isEnabled = isFavorite, where isFavorite is the condition

Comment: From where you are getting the user? You have to save the favorite information into user and then you should set the button state based on that information.

Comment: @Anuraj Thanks for the response. I am new here. Could you please give me a code for that too?

Comment: @KPO Can you please update the question with your current progress/ state so that there is more clarity in requirement ??

Comment: @Anuraj I have written the app. It is storing contact info of all my org's employees. When a user looks for details of a contact it segues to a new view controller. In this view controller I wanted to give a button to tap to add that contact to favourite. When the user taps that button the contact is favourited and the button should stay disabled till the user unfavourites the contact. I hope you are getting what i need.

Comment: @KPO How does he unfavourites the contact, does it have another button to do that?

Comment: @Anuraj Yes..But that button is in a different viewcontroller. That view controller lists all the favourite contacts. One can swipe left on a contact to unfavourite it.(That is what i am planning to code.Not written yet though)

Comment: @KPO See the answer and let me know if you have any queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this func to disable the button :-

```
func changeMakeFavorateBtnState(shouldEnable:Bool) {

    yourButton.isEnabled = shouldEnable
    yourButton.alpha = shouldEnable ? 0.5 :1


}
```

***Even though the button is disabled the user would be able to know that, so changing alpha would do the trick.***

Comment: Thanks dude....I was confused with the wrong things it seems....

Comment: @KPO Please accept if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can unchecked `User Interaction Enabled` for your button in storyboard inspector.
And when you will reload your view check dependencies and set `button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` if needed.

Comment: Vitaly.....That is what i want to know....How do you do all that programatically?